# MySQL filter by values in a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to execute a MySQL query kind of

```
select * from table where id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3 or id = 4 or id = 5 or id = 6
```

Is there any expression to reduce the sql grouping the values?, something like

```
select * from table where id oneof (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I have the same question for and and and and ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to use `in` function.

```
select * from table where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: Thank you! What would be the solution for a sql like -> select * from table where name like %exp1% and like %exp2% and like %exp3% and ...

Comment: Well like wildcard `%%` is really a bottleneck for a large data set. You may check out mysql full text search instead